# How to continue a set of equations in the following page using an align environment

Tags: equations, align

I have this Latex code to define a set of equations:

```
\begin{equation}
    \min~(Cost, P^{Peak}) \label{eq:objective_function}
\end{equation}

subject to:

\begin{align}
    &T^{min}_{b} \leq T^{Building}_{t,b} \leq T^{max}_{b} \label{eq:temperature_balance} \\
    &V^{DHWmin}_{b} \leq V^{DHW}_{t,b} \leq V^{DHWmax}_{b} \label{eq:DHW_balance} \\
    & T^{Building}_{Z,b} \geq T^{Building}_{1,b} \cdot d^{Building} \label{eq:Tempeature_End_Value} \\
    & V^{DHW}_{Z,b} \geq V^{DHW}_{1,b} \cdot d^{DHW} \label{eq:DHW_End_Value} \\
    &T^{Building}_{t,b} = T^{Building}_{t-1, b} + \frac{Q_{t,b}^{SH} - Q_{t,b}^{DemandSH} -  Q_{t,b}^{LossesSH}}{V^{UFH}_b \cdot  \rho^{Concrete} \cdot c^{Concrete}} \label{eq:temperature_difference_equation} \\
    &V^{DHW}_{t,b} = V^{DHW}_{t-1, b} + \frac{Q_{t,b}^{DHW} - Q_{t,b}^{DemandDHW} -  Q_{t,b}^{LossesDHW}}{T^{DHW} \cdot  \rho^{Water} \cdot c^{Water}} \label{eq:volume_difference_equation} \\
    &Q_{t,b}^{SH} = x_{t,b} \cdot P^{HP}_b  \cdot COP_{t,b} \cdot \Delta t \label{eq:heating_energy_HP_SH} \\
    &Q_{t,b}^{SH} = y_{t,b} \cdot P^{HP}_b  \cdot COP_{t,b} \cdot \Delta t \label{eq:heating_energy_HP_DHW} \\
    &h_{t-1,b}^{runSH} + h_{t-1,b}^{runDHW} \leq h_{t,b}^{runSH} + h_{t,b}^{runDHW} + h_{t,b}^{switchedOff} \label{eq:numer_of_switch_offs_1} \\
    &h_{t,b}^{runSH} + h_{t,b}^{runDHW} \leq 1 \label{eq:numer_of_switch_offs_2} \\
    & \sum_{t=1}^{T} h_{t,b}^{switchedOff} \leq k_b \label{eq:numer_of_switch_offs_3} \\
    &x_{t,b} \leq h_{t,b}^{runSH} \label{eq:min_mod_SH_1} \\
    &x_{t,b} \geq h_{t,b}^{runSH} \cdot mod^{min} \label{eq:min_mod_SH_2} \\
    &y_{t,b} \leq h_{t,b}^{runDHW} \label{eq:min_mod_DHW_1} \\
    &y_{t,b} \geq h_{t,b}^{runDHW} \cdot mod^{min} \label{eq:min_mod_DHW_1} \\
    &P_{t,b}^{EV} \leq P_{t,b}^{EVMax} \cdot a_{t,b} \label{eq:max_power_EV} \\
    %&0 \leq SOC_{t,b} \leq 1 \label{eq:SOC_Balance} \\
    %& SOC_{Z,b} \geq SOC_{1,b} \cdot d^{SOC} \label{eq:SOC_End_Value} \\
    & SOC_{t,b} = SOC_{t-1,b} + \frac{P_{t,b}^{EV} \cdot \eta{b} \cdot \Delta t - P_{t,b}^{EVDrive} \cdot \Delta t}{C^{EV}_b} \label{eq:soc_difference_equation} \\
    &Cost = \sum_{t=1}^{Z} \sum_{b=1}^{B} ((x_{t,b} + y_{t,b}) \cdot P^{HP}_b + P_{t,b}^{EV} + P_{t,b}^{el}) \cdot \Delta t \cdot p_t   \label{eq:objective_cost} \\
    %&P^{Peak} =  \max_{t} \Bigg\{\sum_{b=1}^{B} ((x_{t,b} + y_{t,b}) \cdot P^{HP}_b + P_{t,b}^{EV} + P_{t,b}^{el})\Bigg\} \label{eq:peak} \\
    &\begin{aligned}
    &x_{t,b} \in [0,1], &\quad &y_{t,b} \in [0,1], \\
    &h_{t,b}^{runSH} \in \{0,1\}, & &h_{t,b}^{runDHW} \in \{0,1\}, \quad h_{t,b}^{switchedOff} \in \{0,1\}
    \end{aligned} 
\end{align}
```

I commented some equations out  and the output is good as you can see in the screenshot.
[image]

However, when adding these further equations, the output looks really strange as you can see in the following screenshot
[image]

Strangely Latex starts a very new page with the equations and even more strangley, it continues to write the equations even when the border of the page is reached. This is super weird (and I can't think of any rationale as to why any typesetting tool would do something like that). So how can I tell Latex to just continue with the equations on the next page?

Comment: Maybe use `split` instead of align here? (Or even just displayed formulas that are not centered but flushleft with some margin.) But, do you really want to stack all these formulas like that?

Comment: `align` will break over a page if you use `\allowdisplaybreaks` somewhere berore it eg the preamble also `Peak` etc should be `\mathrm{Peak}` don't use math italic for words it is designed to look like the product of 1-letter variables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and mickep: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Why shall I "don't use math italic for words it is designed to look like the product of 1-letter variables."? What do you mean by 1-letter variables and product?

Comment: @PeterBe in text `abc` is some unknown word but in math `abc` means a times b times c, so the default math font has wide sidebearings and no ligatures to keep letters separate, compare `$diff+\mathrm{diff}+\mathit{diff}$` you will see the difference

Comment: oh no need for my diff example look at your `switchedOff` image above, tex is trying hard to keep the f apart so you do not read it as "off"  compare to Mico's version with using mathrm

Comment: Off-topic: You employ `T` both to denote "Temperature" and as the upper limit of summation, as in `\sum_[t=1}{T}...` May I suggest you use a different letter than `T` to indicate the upper limit of summation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing both of @DavidCarlisle's suggestions, one gets:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \displaybreaks macro and 'align' a safe environment
\allowdisplaybreaks
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % "vn": short for "variable name"

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:objective_function}
    \min (\vn{Cost}, P^{\vn{Peak}}) 
\end{equation}
subject to:
\begin{align}
    &T^{\min}_{b} \leq T^{\vn{Building}}_{t,b} \leq T^{\max}_{b} 
       \label{eq:temperature_balance} \\
    &V^{\vn{DHWmin}}_{b} \leq V^{\vn{DHW}}_{t,b} \leq V^{\vn{DHWmax}}_{b} 
       \label{eq:DHW_balance} \\
    & T^{\vn{Building}}_{Z,b} \geq T^{\vn{Building}}_{1,b} \cdot d^{\vn{Building}} 
       \label{eq:Tempeature_End_Value} \\
    & V^{\vn{DHW}}_{Z,b} \geq V^{\vn{DHW}}_{1,b} \cdot d^{\vn{DHW}} 
       \label{eq:DHW_End_Value} \\
    &T^{\vn{Building}}_{t,b} = T^{\vn{Building}}_{t-1,b} 
        + \frac{Q_{t,b}^{\vn{SH}} - Q_{t,b}^{\vn{DemandSH}} -  Q_{t,b}^{\vn{LossesSH}}}%
               {V^{\vn{UFH}}_b \cdot  \rho^{\vn{Concrete}} \cdot c^{\vn{Concrete}}} 
       \label{eq:temperature_difference_equation} \\
    &V^{\vn{DHW}}_{t,b} = V^{\vn{DHW}}_{t-1, b} 
       + \frac{Q_{t,b}^{\vn{DHW}} - Q_{t,b}^{\vn{DemandDHW}} -  Q_{t,b}^{\vn{LossesDHW}}}%
              {T^{\vn{DHW}} \cdot  \rho^{\vn{Water}} \cdot c^{\vn{Water}}} 
       \label{eq:volume_difference_equation} \\
    &Q_{t,b}^{\vn{SH}} = x_{t,b} \cdot P^{\vn{HP}}_b  \cdot \vn{COP}_{t,b} \cdot \Delta t 
       \label{eq:heating_energy_HP_SH} \\
    &Q_{t,b}^{\vn{SH}} = y_{t,b} \cdot P^{\vn{HP}}_b  \cdot \vn{COP}_{t,b} \cdot \Delta t 
       \label{eq:heating_energy_HP_DHW} \\
    &h_{t-1,b}^{\vn{runSH}} + h_{t-1,b}^{\vn{runDHW}} 
       \leq h_{t,b}^{\vn{runSH}} + h_{t,b}^{\vn{runDHW}} + h_{t,b}^{\vn{switchedOff}} 
       \label{eq:numer_of_switch_offs_1} \\
    &h_{t,b}^{\vn{runSH}} + h_{t,b}^{\vn{runDHW}} \leq 1 
       \label{eq:numer_of_switch_offs_2} \\
    & \sum\nolimits_{t=1}^{T} h_{t,b}^{\vn{switchedOff}} \leq k_b 
       \label{eq:numer_of_switch_offs_3} \\
    &x_{t,b} \leq h_{t,b}^{\vn{runSH}} 
       \label{eq:min_mod_SH_1} \\
    &x_{t,b} \geq h_{t,b}^{\vn{runSH}} \cdot {\vn{mod}}^{\min} 
       \label{eq:min_mod_SH_2} \\
    &y_{t,b} \leq h_{t,b}^{\vn{runDHW}} 
       \label{eq:min_mod_DHW_1} \\
    &y_{t,b} \geq h_{t,b}^{\vn{runDHW}} \cdot {\vn{mod}}^{\min} 
       \label{eq:min_mod_DHW_1} \\
    &P_{t,b}^{\vn{EV}} \leq P_{t,b}^{\vn{EVMax}} \cdot a_{t,b} 
       \label{eq:max_power_EV} \\
    &0 \leq \vn{SOC}_{t,b} \leq 1 
       \label{eq:SOC_Balance} \\
    & \vn{SOC}_{Z,b} \geq \vn{SOC}_{1,b} \cdot d^{\vn{SOC}} 
          \label{SOC_End_Value} \\
    & \vn{SOC}_{t,b} = \vn{SOC}_{t-1,b} 
       +\frac{P_{t,b}^{\vn{EV}} \cdot \eta{b} \cdot \Delta t - P_{t,b}^{\vn{EVDrive}} \cdot \Delta t}%
             {C^{\vn{EV}}_b} 
       \label{eq:soc_difference_equation} \\
    &\vn{Cost} = \sum\nolimits_{t=1}^{Z} \sum\nolimits_{b=1}^{B} 
                 ((x_{t,b} + y_{t,b}) \cdot P^{\vn{HP}}_b + P_{t,b}^{\vn{EV}} + P_{t,b}^{\vn{el}}) 
                 \cdot \Delta t \cdot p_t   
       \label{eq:objective_cost} \\
    &P^{\vn{Peak}} =  \max_{t} \Bigl\{ 
       \sum\nolimits_{b=1}^{B} \bigl((x_{t,b} + y_{t,b}) \cdot P^{\vn{HP}}_b + P_{t,b}^{\vn{EV}} + P_{t,b}^{\vn{el}}\bigr)\Bigr\} \label{eq:peak} \\
    &\begin{aligned}
       &x_{t,b} \in [0,1], 
          && y_{t,b} \in [0,1], \\
       &h_{t,b}^{\vn{runSH}} \in \{0,1\}, 
          && h_{t,b}^{\vn{runDHW}} \in \{0,1\}, 
          && h_{t,b}^{\vn{switchedOff}} \in \{0,1\}
     \end{aligned} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico for your answer. It was helpful.